# Refresh token for Dashboards

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I know we have a Refresh token working for Reports and on the old issue list I have raised a ticket for refreshing Dashboards token. Has this been fixed?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

`dashboard.setToken(...)` should be working just fine.. is it not working for you? what's the error you're receiving?